# How do I make a different file run python code

Tags: python

I have been making a program that opens a different file (extension is .ebj) and shows you the 3d object saved inside it with pygame, so kind of like a simple programming language. Currently i have found how to choose what file you want to open using sys.argv but is there a way to make it so you can run the .ebj file and it will automatically  run the python code with the file you ran as the parameter

Answer (score 2):

You description is a bit difficult to decipher.  I think you need your python script to run a file?  That's what I'm assuming after seeing your reference to sys.argv as holding the file you'd like to run.

If I have that correct, then how you go about running that file is going to be dependent on which OS you're operating on.  I'll assume windows, but forgive me if I'm off on that.

Here's how I have my windows machine run a software package using the windows default application based on the file ext.

```
import subprocess

filename = GET_YOUR_FILENAME_HERE

subprocess.call("start " + filename, shell=True)
```

Comment: I don't need python to run another file, I need another file to run a python script

Comment: Ahh...  you probably just need to prepend 'python" before the filename then.  If you run a python script from the command line, you often need to put python in front of the script name.  It's not uncommon for the windows file association to not work as expected when running outside of the windows environment.    So if you know how to make your other file perform a call to a "normal" software package, then just use "python myfile.py" instead of "myfile.py" when you try to "run" it.  Does that work?

Comment: I don't mean that, i mean instead of having to put in the command you just run a file and it will include the file you run as a parameter

Comment: So for example, you run your program.  That opens your .ebj file and performs some action, then the output of that becomes the parameter of your python file?  I'm sorry but it's hard to follow.  You're talking about 3 total files, so I'm getting lost in what you're running, what and where the python file is in the process, and when you're using the ebj file.

Comment: You run the ebj file, that opens the python file and includes the filename of the ebj file as a parameter of the python file

Comment: How can I make it so I can run the ebj file

Comment: I don't know how you run an EBJ file, because I'm not familiar with them.  You want the EBJ file to open the python file, then the python file has the EBJ filename as a parameter?

Comment: the ebj file is only exclusively for the program I'm making. Is there a way to let Windows run any for extension as a command

Comment: I think I finally understand what you're asking.  You want to be able to click on your EBJ file and have it run with the associated Windows application (that you're making), at the same time, you want the python script to run while having the EBJ filename as the python parameter.  Do I have it right that time?

Comment: Yes but I just want it to be able to run the python script, that is the thing that I'm making

Comment: I need to leave for the day.  But I think there are a couple issues with your plan.  You can't, to my knowledge, create two events to trigger upon the opening of a single file-type...  So either you need to have the app that is associated with the EBJ file open the appropriate python script, or you need the python script to open the EBJ file with the appropriate application, essentially making your own association.  Basically, the windows associate to the EBJ would be your python script, and then THAT script would then open the EBJ file with the seperate application you mentioned.

Comment: But unfortunately I need to go.  I wish you luck.  I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: The python file is the only app associated with the ebj file, it just needs to run the python file when you run it